# Limiting behaviour of solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t)$ be non constant matrix valued continuous function such that every solution of

$$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$$

has a limit at infinity. How to show that if $x(t)$ is non zero solution then its limit at infinity also non zero? I'm trying to show it by assuming the limit of non zero solution is zero, but I can't obtain any contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.  Suppose e.g. $A(t) = -I$ for sufficiently large $t$.